# Run tests in TestCafé Studio via command

Tags: testing, cmd, automated-tests, testcafe, test-results

How can I execute a test via command in a way that the test run is shown with all its results in TestCafé Studio afterwards?

I'm using:

*npx testcafe [browser] [TestCafe file]*

The test is executed but the results are only visible in the console. Is there a way to fully integrate it in TestCafé Studio?

BTW: Why isn't there a tag for [testcafestudio] – the product is not that new ;-)

---

EDIT: I'll take a little further out: We would like to switch from TestCafé to TestCafé Studio to increase the number of people who can maintain and create individual tests in QA. Some tasks could then also be handled by employees with somewhat lower HTML skills. In addition, we would like to keep the connections we are used to, so that the tests are still triggered at certain times or manually via a Jenkins pipeline (Jenkins-->VIX-->CMD-->TestCafé Studio). Depending on the configuration of the respective test run, different branches would be used for the TestCafé Studio project via Git. The test results are read, parsed, and written to a database after the test run is complete.  In addition, I would like to see the atomatically triggered calls available in TestCafé Studio, as it is very convenient to navigate directly to the failed tests.
Is it not yet possible to start tests in TestCafé Studio via CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe Studio stores reports in its own format while TestCafe stores reports in [various different formats](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/reporters.html) that are inconsistent with the IDE format.

You can run tests in the TestCafe Studio itself. Are you running your tests in CI? If so, what CI are you using and why does not its reporting system meet your requirements? If not, could you please clarify why you are required to run tests outside the TestCafe Studio IDE?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the background and added an explanation to my request text. Because of the character limitation it did not fit into the comment here.

Comment: The IDE does not allow you run tests in command-line mode.